# can't call - this - inside youtube api event (onReady etc )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I can't call any function or variable inside my function

I have onReady event ( youtube api event )

also when i do console.log(this) the result is undefined inside the function

this is my typescript code

```
isOn :boolean =   false;

createPlayer(): void {
  return new window['YT'].Player(this.youtube.playerId, {
    height: this.youtube.playerHeight,
    width: this.youtube.playerWidth,
    playerVars: {
      rel: 0,
      showinfo: 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': this.onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': this.state,
    }
  });
}


public state(event) {
  this.isOn = true; //here is the problem and the result is not defined 
}
```

> //this  class from   ionic 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **arrow functions** like this:

```
isOn :boolean =   false;

createPlayer(): void {
  return new window['YT'].Player(this.youtube.playerId, {
    height: this.youtube.playerHeight,
    width: this.youtube.playerWidth,
    playerVars: {
      rel: 0,
      showinfo: 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': () => { /* Put your logic here! */ }
      'onStateChange': () => { this.isOn = true; /* Now it should work! */ }
    }
  });
}
```

When using a regular function, the this keyword references the function itself, but when using arrow functions, **the this property is not overwritten and still references the component instance** (where you defined the navCtrl property).